# Checking list of conditions on API data

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, quartz.net

I am using an API which is sending some data about products, every 1 second.
on the other hand I have a list of user-created conditions. And I want to check if any data that comes, matches any of the conditions. and if so, I want to notify the user.

for example , user condition maybe like this : `price < 30000 and productName = 'chairNumber2'`

and the data would be something like this :
`{'data':[{'name':'chair1','price':'20000','color':blue},{'name':'chairNumber2','price':'45500','color':green},{'name':'chairNumber2','price':'27000','color':blue}]`

I am using microservice architecture, and on validating condition I am sending a message on RabbitMQ to my notification service

I have tried the naïve solution (every 1 second, check every condition , and if any data meets the condition then pass on data my other service)
but this takes so much RAM and time(time order is in n*m,n being the count of conditions, and m is the count of data), so I am looking for a better scenario

Comment: Roughly how many users do you have now, and how many do you need to allow for in the future?  How many product updates are there every second, and is this expected to increase?  For an individual product, how often does it's data change?

Comment: Product updates are every second, but how fast must you inform users?

Comment: these all should be really fast , the products and users are generic, it could be a simple OMS product, or stock market share, or scientific data that I'm monitoring

Comment: Unfortunately "really fast" is too vague.  A precise target helps inform architecture decision making.  Look at availability for example: the difference between 99.99 & 99.999 may not seem like much but in reality it might cost $$$ to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an interesting problem.  I have to confess I don't really know how I would do it - it depends a lot on exactly how fast the processing needs to occur, and a lot of other factors not mentioned - such as what constraints to do you have in terms of the technology stack you have, is it on-premise or in the cloud, must the solution be coded by you/your team or can you buy some $$ tool.  For future reference, for architecture questions especially, any context you can provide is really helpful - e.g. constraints.

I did think of **Pub-Sub**, which may offer patterns you can use, but you really just need a simple implementation that will work within your code base, AND very importantly you only have one consuming client, the RabbitMQ queue - it's not like you have X number of random clients wanting the data.  So an off-the-shelf Pub-Sub solution might not be a good fit.

Assuming you want a "home-grown" solution, this is what has come to mind so far:

[image]

*("flow" connectors show data flow, which could be interpreted as a 'push'; where as the other lines are UML "dependency" lines; e.g. the match engine depends on data held in the batch, but it's agnostic as to how that happens).*

- The **external data source** is where the data is coming from.  I had not made any assumptions about how that works or what control you have over it.
- **Interface**, all this does is take the raw data and put it into batches that can be processed later by the **Match Engine**.  How the interface works depends on how you want to balance (a) the data coming in, and (b) what you know the match engine expects.
- Batches are thrown into a **batch queue**.  It's job is to ensure that no data is lost before its processed, that processing can be managed (order of batch processing, resilience, etc).
- **Match engine**, works fast on the assumption that the size of each batch is a manageable number of records/changes.  It's job is to take changes and ask who's interested in them, and return the results to the RabbitMQ.  So its inputs are just the batches and the user & user matching rules (more on that later).  How this actually works I'm not sure, worst case it iterates through each rule seeing who has a match - what you're doing now, but...

**Key point:** the queue would also allow you to scale-out the number of match engine instances - **but**, I don't know what affect that has downstream on the RabbitMQ and it's downstream consumers (the order in which the updates would arrive, etc).

**What's not shown:** caching.  The match engine needs to know what the matching rules are, and which users those rules relate to.  The fastest way to do that look-up is probably in memory, not a database read (unless you can be smart about how that happens), which brings me to this addition:

[image]

- **Data Source** is wherever the user data, and user matching rules, are kept.  I have assumed they are external to "Your Solution" but it doesn't matter.
- **Cache** is something that holds the **user matches (rules) & user** data.  It's sole job is to hold these in a way that is optimized for the Match Engine to work fast.  You could logically say it was part of the match engine, or separate.  How you approach this might be determined by whether or not you intend to scale-out the match engine.
- **Data Provider** is simply the component whose job it is to fetch user & rule data and make it available for caching.

So, the Rule engine, cache and data provider could all be separate components, or logically parts of the one component / microservice.

Comment: thanks a lot, I have used some similar architecture, and the caching made it a lot faster
also I have found a platform which solve the same problem , it's called Flink (it's developed by apache)